# Proper Way to Fit a Lognormal Distribution with Weight in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Currently I have code to fit a lognormal distribution.

```
shape,  loc,  scale  = sm.lognorm.fit(dataToLearn, floc = 0)

for b in bounds:
    toPlot.append((b, currCount+sm.lognorm.ppf(b, s = shape, loc = loc, scale = scale)))
```

I would like to be able to pass in a vector of weights to the fitting.  Currently I have a workaround, where I keep all the weights rounded to 2 decimals and then repeat each value `w` times so that it gets weighted properly.

```
for i, d in enumerate(dataToLearn):
    dataToLearn2 += int(w[i] * 100) * [d]
```

The runtime of this is getting too slow for my computer so I was hoping for a more correct solution.

Please advise whether it be using scipy or numpy to make my workaround faster and more efficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SciPy distributions do not implement a weighted fit.  For the log-normal distribution, however, there are explicit formulas for the (unweighted) [maximum likelihood estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Maximum_likelihood_estimation_of_parameters), and these are easily generalized for weighted data. The explicit formulas are both (in effect) averages, and the generalization to the case of weighted data is to use weighted averages in the formulas.

Here's a script that demonstrates the calculation using a small data set with integer weights, so we know what the exact value of the fitted parameters should be.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import lognorm


# Sample data and weights.  To enable an exact comparison with
# the method of generating an array with the values repeated
# according to their weight, I use an array of weights that is
# all integers.
x = np.array([2.5, 8.4, 9.3, 10.8, 6.8, 1.9, 2.0])
w = np.array([  1,   1,   2,    1,   3,   3,   1])


#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Fit the log-normal distribution by creating an array containing the values
# repeated according to their weight.
xx = np.repeat(x, w)

# Use the explicit formulas for the MLE of the log-normal distribution.
lnxx = np.log(xx)
muhat = np.mean(lnxx)
varhat = np.var(lnxx)

shape = np.sqrt(varhat)
scale = np.exp(muhat)

print("MLE using repeated array: shape=%7.5f   scale=%7.5f" % (shape, scale))


#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Use the explicit formulas for the weighted MLE of the log-normal
# distribution.

lnx = np.log(x)
muhat = np.average(lnx, weights=w)
# varhat is the weighted variance of ln(x).  There isn't a function in
# numpy for the weighted variance, so we compute it using np.average.
varhat = np.average((lnx - muhat)**2, weights=w)

shape = np.sqrt(varhat)
scale = np.exp(muhat)

print("MLE using weights:        shape=%7.5f   scale=%7.5f" % (shape, scale))


#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Might as well check that we get the same result from lognorm.fit() using the
# repeated array

shape, loc, scale = lognorm.fit(xx, floc=0)

print("MLE using lognorm.fit:    shape=%7.5f   scale=%7.5f" % (shape, scale))
```

The output is

```
MLE using repeated array:  shape=0.70423   scale=4.57740
MLE using weights:         shape=0.70423   scale=4.57740
MLE using lognorm.fit:     shape=0.70423   scale=4.57740
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) to make the workaround more efficient:

```
import numpy as np

dataToLearn = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
weights = np.array([1,2,1,1,3])

print(np.repeat(dataToLearn, weights))
# Output: array([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5])
```

Very basic performance test of `numpy.repeat` performance:

```
import timeit

code_before = """
weights = np.array([1,2,1,1,3] * 1000)
dataToLearn = np.array([1,2,3,4,5] * 1000)
dataToLearn2 = []
for i, d in enumerate(dataToLearn):
    dataToLearn2 += int(weights[i]) * [d]
"""

code_after = """
weights = np.array([1,2,1,1,3] * 1000)
dataToLearn = np.array([1,2,3,4,5] * 1000)
np.repeat(dataToLearn, weights)
"""

print(timeit.timeit(code_before, setup="import numpy as np", number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit(code_after, setup="import numpy as np", number=1000))
```

As a result, I've got roughly 3.38 for your current approach vs 0.75 for `numpy.repeat`

Comment: thanks leaving open in case this is already implemented (although I found little in the docs)